# Calculating rotation of object in 3D where input is 2 points in 3D space

Tags: c#, math, graphics, 3d

I'm having an issues with beginner tasks in 3D graphics - I have an object (for simplicity lets say it is a cylinder/line), cylinder is set in it's local point of 0,0,0 and has a total length of 1 (0,5 forward, 0,5 backward, 0,5 radius). That way I can apply translation/rotations as I please.

Here is a simplified reference in Blender:
[image: Non-rotated or moved or scaled object]

I want to rotate this object by passing 2 points in 3D space - lets say P1=(0,0,0), P2=(10,10,10) (and possibly the up vector?), in a way that my object passes thru this points.

Here is rough expected result - want to calculate the Euler angles or Quaternion rotation to achieve it:
[image: Expected result - an object between P1=0,0,0 and P2=10,10,10]

The code below works great in my own engine, but it has issues if any of the points have Z (I'm using X,Y,Z where Z = up/down) position !=0.

```
        public static Rotation RotationSpanningBetween2Points(VertexPosition vertexStart, VertexPosition vertexEnd)
        {
            double dx = vertexEnd.position.X - vertexStart.position.X;
            double dy = vertexEnd.position.Y - vertexStart.position.Y;
            double dz = vertexEnd.position.Z - vertexStart.position.Z;


            return new Rotation(
                    RadToDeg(Math.Atan2(dz, dy)),
                    RadToDeg(Math.Atan2(dz, dx)),
                    RadToDeg(Math.Atan2(dx, dy)));
        }
```

The solution seems somewhat simple but it escapes me.

Comment: When you rotate the object has to be along the line.  When you have a z offset the object is not on the line.  You would first need to move the z location so it is on the line and then rotate.

Comment: @jdweng okay, so by move the z location you mean not moving the object, but it's own Z-axis? so I spin it by X and Y, then I should somehow rotate it by original Z axis? How I'm  suppose to calculate that?

Comment: Draw a vertical line through the object and then find where the vertical line and your line intersect.